# Digispark - Bootloader stuck

Tags: attiny85

I have a digispark that I want to reprogram, soldered into a circuit. I have burned the default t85 micronucleus firmware.

**This is the command I used:**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude" -C "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf" -v -pattiny85 -cstk500v1 -PCOM4 -b19200 -Uflash:w:D:\Documents\micronucleus-master\firmware\releases\t85_default.hex:i

avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Sep 12 2016 at 17:24:16
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM4
         Using Programmer              : stk500v1
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
         AVR Part                      : ATtiny85
         Chip Erase delay              : 400000 us
         PAGEL                         : P00
         BS2                           : P00
         RESET disposition             : possible i/o
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    12     4    0 no        512    4      0  4000  4500 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6    32    0 yes      8192   64    128 30000 30000 0xff 0xff
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : STK500
         Description     : Atmel STK500 Version 1.x firmware
         Hardware Version: 2
         Firmware Version: 1.18
         Topcard         : Unknown
         Vtarget         : 0.0 V
         Varef           : 0.0 V
         Oscillator      : Off
         SCK period      : 0.1 us

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.03s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e930b (probably t85)
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as D7
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as FF
avrdude: NOTE: "flash" memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed
         To disable this feature, specify the -D option.
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: reading input file "D:\Documents\micronucleus-master\firmware\releases\t85_default.hex"
avrdude: writing flash (8116 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.07s

avrdude: 8116 bytes of flash written
avrdude: verifying flash memory against D:\Documents\micronucleus-master\firmware\releases\t85_default.hex:
avrdude: load data flash data from input file D:\Documents\micronucleus-master\firmware\releases\t85_default.hex:
avrdude: input file D:\Documents\micronucleus-master\firmware\releases\t85_default.hex contains 8116 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.07s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 8116 bytes of flash verified

avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as D7
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as FF
avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (E:FF, H:D7, L:F1)

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

I have not set any fuses (I hope the frequency is right.)

The board is recognized by my computer and I can program a sketch into it using Arduino IDE. Despite all this the program I burned into it does not run. It seems it is stuck into the bootloader section.

**The sketch:**

```
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(0, HIGH); 
}
```

Pin `PB0` has never a voltage bigger than `1.7V`(noise or floating). All pins have similar voltages (except `PB3`,`PB4` which are pulled up or high)

**The schematic:**
[image]

The circuit works. I tested both displays previously with the atiny which I directly programmed with the `Uno`. The upper right connector is directly plugged into the `digispark` with the following pins: `VIN`,`GND`,`5V`. The middle connector is also plugged into the `digispark`.

**I have tried:**

- Powered by USB: I am afraid this will be detected by the bootloader and enter the programming state thus never running the schematic(shouldn't happen but you never know...)
- Powered by VIN with a 9V battery. Nothing. All voltages are in check (`5V pin` has `5v` on it. All other pins are floating)
- Powered by `5V pin` using an `Arduino UNO` as the source. Nothing.
  In all cases the voltage on PB0 stays the same. It varies between `0.6V` and `1.6V`.

**In Arduino IDE:**

- Tried Digispark 16.5Mhz
- Digispark Pro 16Mhz
- Digispark(No Usb) 16Mhz

Always a succesfull uploading.

**Notes:**

- After uploading in Arduino this text comes up:

  > Starting the user app ...
  >   running: 100% complete

  So it is supposed to run the program but the board actually resets because it gets renumerated by windows.
- It's not quite possible to de-solder it and program the sketch directly with `Arduino` as `ISP`
- I use Windows 10
- Fuses used when I burned the `micronucleus` `L:F1` `H:D7` `E:FF`. These are the default "safe" values. The actual fuses needed by the firmware are `L:E1` `H:DD` `E:FE`.
- Difference in extended fuse: Self-programming is curently disabled...Is this the culprit?
- I managed to desolder `PB0`,`PB1` and `PB2` from the back of the pcb. Now I can't program it directly with `Arduino as ISP`. The setup I have should work because I can easily program an t45. So it has something to do with the digispark. Checked the connection between pins and the actual MCU. The error I get is `Yikes...` and sometimes it finds an 0x00ff00 or other junk id for the board but probably it's because of misconnection.

**Question #2:**

In the current configuration(soldered) would it be possible to use again  `Arduino as ISP` to program it?  `PB0`,`PB1`,`PB2` are connected to `Serial Clock`,`Serial Data` and `Serial Storage Clock` respectively. I am trying right now to set the right fuses but every time I get this:

```
avrdude -C "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr\etc\avrdude.conf" -c stk500v1 -p attiny85  -U lfuse:w:0xe1:m -U hfuse:w:0xdd:m -U efuse:w:0xfe:m -B 20 -b19200 -P COM7

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.06s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000 (retrying)

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.05s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000 (retrying)

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.05s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000
avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.


avrdude done.  Thank you.

make: *** [fuse] Error 1
```

Comment: Your schematic needs some work. For example the connector(?) in the upper right corner, I can't tell what order the pins are in. I can't tell what the names of the resistors are (because they layer on top of each other). There are dangling wires (stubs) and it seems like a lot of spaghetti. There are no capacitors anywhere so that might be an issue.

Comment: The upper connector is for power. It is directly pulled into digispark. So is the middle connector. Digispark already provide the capacitors for the power. And yes..It still needs a lot of work. BUT the schematic works. Tested both screens with numbers by directly programming the attiny.

Comment: This is driving me crazy. Since I programmed this bootloader nothing works. I think it is software related because the board works..in its way. It is recognized by the pc, I can program it..but it executes nothing it should have.

Comment: have you read this? https://digistump.com/wiki/digispark/tutorials/connecting

Comment: I programmed the digisprk a hundred times before. It always worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! I don't know what the real issue was but I constructed a HV programmer and just blasted the digispark with the new and proper fuses. Now it works as it should.